# Difference between Angular Services & session storage

Tags: angular

Why do we need to use session storage when we have angular services to share data across components/modules ?

When we need to use services and when we can go for session storage?

Comment: Session storage survives page reloads

Comment: But keep in mind that sessionStorage is browser-tab exclusive (might need localStorage in some cases).

Comment: As @jabaa mentioned, session storage persists across page reloads (F5, or the refresh button near the URL bar of your browser), but it gets deleted when you close the tab. If you want something persistent even when the tab/browser/pc is closed, then go for local storage. If you don't need the levels of persistence described here, go for an angular service instead.